# iOs app localization: loading strings from server

Tags: ios, localization

I'd like to be able to load translations in a JSON file (array of key value pairs) from a remote server at application boot or whenever deemed necessary, and keep the file locally on the device, as opposed to hardcoding into a .strings file.

I will be using this for labels, buttons and the like. All application data will already be translated on server side.

This will make it easy to add/remove languages/translations.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

I would advice to save them under in a dictionary, and save this dictionary under `NSUserDefaults` (`NSUserdefaults` will let this dictionary save and stay even when your app force closes. As long as you don't remove it in a function or uninstall the application).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would I not have to set the text for each element from the view controllers on load if using this approach? Sdownloading the translations and storing them is trivial but I am also looking for a dev-friendly way to apply those translations to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [LocalizationKit](https://github.com/willpowell8/LocalizationKit_iOS). This kit doing exactly what you described.

Another way is to dowload resource while app is loading and save all translation in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: I've seen LocalizationKit, please correct me if I am wrong but it seems I would depend on their service. I want something I can store and manage on my machines.

Comment: @NickM yes, you are right. Localization will be stored on the server. Unfortunately, source for the server is not available.

Comment: That's no biggie, I can write the server side for something like this in under a day but I was hoping to find some alternative so I won't get sidetracked.